# Updating rails has_many through relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, models

I have models

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specializations
  has_many :cruise_lines, through: :specializations
end

class CruiseLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specializations
  has_many :agencies, through: :specializations
end

class Specialization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency, inverse_of: :specializations
  belongs_to :cruise_line, inverse_of: :specializations
end
```

I want to update `Specialization` collection (that is delete some of old relations and add a few new if needed). My method that should update relations looks like this (inside some separate service):

```
def self.update_agency_specializations(agency, params)
  attributes = params.require(:agency).permit( { cruise_line_ids: [] } )

  attributes[:cruise_line_ids].select{ |x| x.to_i > 0 }.each do |cruise_line_id|
    agency.specializations.build(cruise_line_id: cruise_line_id)
  end
  return false if agency.errors.present?
  true
end
```

But this does basically nothing, however, in combination with updating agency - this exact code worked. What am I doing wrong?

In current implementation it issues error `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_specializations_on_agency_id_and_cruise_line_id" DETAIL: Key (agency_id, cruise_line_id)=(1, 3) already exists.` So that means that it tries to save new relations having not yet deleted old ones, so it violates index of entries that are the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First solution:**

```
def self.update_agency_specializations(agency, params)
  attributes = params.require(:agency).permit( { cruise_line_ids: [] } )

    agency.cruise_line_ids = attributes[:cruise_line_ids].select{ |x| x.to_i > 0 }
    agency.save
  end
  !agency.errors.present?
end
```

In short, don't build anything. Let Rails do the job.

**Second solution:**

```
def self.update_agency_specializations(agency, params)
  attributes = params.require(:agency).permit( { cruise_line_ids: [] } )

  persisted = true
  begin 
    Agency.transaction do 
      agency.specializations.destroy_all
      attributes[:cruise_line_ids].select{ |x| x.to_i > 0 }.each do |cruise_line_id|
        agency.specializations.build(cruise_line_id: cruise_line_id)
      end
      agency.save!
    end 
  rescue RecordInvalid => e
    persisted = false
  end
  persisted
end
```

It is the extension of your approach and should do the job. Note that in this case all `specializations` are destroyed first and then rebuild eventually.

Comment: Perfect! Thanx, you saved my evening! (btw, I also wanted to do in transaction, but first approach is cleaner and nice)

Comment: Where should I put this method? Should this be in the controller? Also it seems the should change in different controllers, is the correct method name update_<model>_<associations>?