# Wrong number of arguments error with has_many :through association and form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, strong-parameters

I have three models related using has_many :through as seen below. The user should be able to select concerns (in addition to insurance, patient gender, preferred gender, and writing a note) and create a referral request. When I try to submit the referral request form I get a wrong number of arguments error as seen in this screenshot.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZR0J.png)

I know this must have something to do with how I am whitelisting my params and have tried a lot of different variations but can't seem to get the syntax (or something else) right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

From Referral Requests Controller:

```
  def create
        @referral_request = current_user.referral_requests.build(referral_request_params)
        if @referral_request.save
            flash[:success] = "Referral Request Created!"
            render 'referral_requests/index'
         else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

    def destroy
    end

private

def referral_request_params
    params.require(:referral_request).permit(:content, :patient_gender_id, 
        :preferred_gender_id, :insurance_id, :concern_ids [])

end
end
```

my referral request form

```
<%= form_for(@referral_request) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <% Concern.all.each do |concern| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "referral_request[concern_ids][]", concern.id %>
    <%= concern.name %><br>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new referral request..." %>
    <%= collection_select( :referral_request, :patient_gender_id, Gender.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %> 
    <%= collection_select( :referral_request, :preferred_gender_id, Gender.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
  <%= collection_select( :referral_request, :insurance_id, Insurance.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Referral Request Model

```
class ReferralRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :referral_request_concerns
  has_many :concerns, through: :referral_request_concerns
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { minimum: 20 }
  validates :patient_gender_id, presence: true
  validates :preferred_gender_id, presence: true
  validates :insurance_id, presence: true
end
```

Concern Model

```
class Concern < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :referral_request_concerns
    has_many :referral_requests, through: :referral_request_concerns
end
```

ReferralRequestConcern Model

```
class ReferralRequestConcern < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :referral_request
    belongs_to :concern
    validates :referral_request_id, presence: true
    validates :concern_id, presence: true
end
```

Here is the output of the create action and associated error log after changing :concern_ids [] to concern_ids: []

```
Started POST "/referral_requests" for ::1 at 2017-06-27 15:01:54 -0400
Processing by ReferralRequestsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9gd2J+PB6R1jRkpwIlJ8KNlFBdxoFuZ5W2c1NAL1aiBv7mhrKT7ITBtxZPd9jpJ49UAGpc4/4jOpAbrlenG91A==", "referral_request"=>{"concern_ids"=>["1", "2", "3", "4"], "content"=>"dsdfsdsdsfggfdsgfdfgdsgfdfgsdgfsdgfdsgfdgfd", "patient_gender_id"=>"2", "preferred_gender_id"=>"2", "insurance_id"=>"16"}, "commit"=>"Post"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Concern Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "concerns".* FROM "concerns" WHERE "concerns"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.1ms)
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f8c2a399d70 @base=#<ReferralRequest id: nil, content: "dsdfsdsdsfggfdsgfdfgdsgfdfgsdgfsdgfdsgfdgfd", insurance: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, insurance_id: 16, patient_gender_id: 2, preferred_gender_id: 2>, @messages={:referral_request_concerns=>["is invalid"]}, @details={:referral_request_concerns=>[{:error=>:invalid}, {:error=>:invalid}, {:error=>:invalid}, {:error=>:invalid}]}>
Completed 200 OK in 131ms (Views: 79.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def referral_request_params
    params.require(:referral_request).permit(:content, :patient_gender_id, 
        :preferred_gender_id, :insurance_id, concern_ids: [])

end
```

(`concern_ids: []` instead of `:concern_ids []`)

Comment: Thanks for catching that Sergey! I no longer get the wrong number of arguments error, but the POST attempt to "/referral requests" now rolls back after beginning the transaction. Do you know what else I should check?

Comment: check referral_request_params inside create action and @referral_request.errors after save is failed.

Comment: I just added the output of the create action and associated error log to the bottom of my original question. It is odd that in the error it says insurance is nil, because I don't have insurance in my controller or in my model - just insurance_id.

Comment: looks like "concern_ids"=>["1", "2", "3", "4"] is not correct format for creating relations on record creation. You can try remove concern_ids: [] from referral_request_params and manually add it (for sample @referral_request.requests = Request.where(id: params['referral_request']['concern_ids'])) or take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/a/26979885/2174582

Comment: I don't know why, but removing the two presence validations from my ReferralRequestConcern model fixed this. Thanks for your help!